# DjangoTemplate + Javascript - How to compare javascript variable with django multiple values

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

How to compare javascript variable "var1" with django multiple values. **If a answer is ok, program should say ¡very good!**

**Django + Javascript:**

```
<script>
var var1 = document.getElementById("userAnswer").value;
        if (
            {% for textEUS in question.textEUS.all %}
                var1 == {{ textEUS }}
            {% endfor %}
        ){
            alert(¡Very good!);
        }
</script>
```

**only Django:**

```
    {% for textEUS in question.textEUS.all %}
        {{ textEUS }}
    {% endfor %}
```

**only Javascript:**

```
<script>
function tocorrect(){
        var var1 = document.getElementById("userAnswer").value;
        if (var1 == "answer"){
            alert(¡Very good!);
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible the way you're trying to do it. This is the order of things:

1. Django renders a page using the django template language. This page might consist of HTML, javascript, and text really. All of the django tags, filters, variables have been assessed and processed at this point. For example:

```
    {% for textEUS in question.textEUS.all %}
        {{ textEUS }}
    {% endfor %}
```

will have turned into a list of text.

2. The page rendered above is sent to your users browser
3. In the browser, the page is loaded, and javascript is executed, but at this point there are no more django template-tags etc.

The key point is:

#### You can't expect django template tags to 'run' at the sametime as your javascript. One happens on the backend, the other on the frontend.

You can however set a javascript variable using the django template language in the backend, and then use it in the front-end:

```
<script>
var var1 = document.getElementById("userAnswer").value;

// create a variable called textEusAll, this is completed in the backend
// before the page is sent to the user
var textEusAll = [
     {% for textEUS in question.textEUS.all %}
         "{{ textEUS }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
]

// use plain javascript for stuff happening in the front-end
if (textEusAll.includes(var1)) {
    alert("¡Very good!");
}            
</script>
```

Comment: @julian I just noticed i typo in this, it should have said `.includes(var1)` i have now corrected this.